# Check if a file exists in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and need to check if a certain system is installed on the machine, which is windows. I'm thinking of doing this by checking for the existence of some files, but I'm not finding how to do this check in typescript.
Would anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: What are you targetting; Node? Browser File API? etc.

Comment: No, I need to check if a .dll is present in a given directory.'

Comment: **TypeScript** might be the wrong language, it doesn't have an API behind it to check existence of files on a machine, like .NET does (`System.IO`). TypeScript compiles to JavaScript and executes in the browser, on NodeJS...anywhere there's a JavaScript runtime. It doesn't compile and run directly on the machine, and therefore doesn't have any access to the underlying operating system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fs.stat(path, (exists) => {
            if (exists == null) {
                return true;
            } else if (exists.code === 'ENOENT') {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: In this context what is `fs`?

Comment: A little late, but for completion's sake it's File System

Comment: More specifically, `fs` is the File System module provided by node. You can import it by including the line `import fs from 'fs'` at the beginning of your .js file

Answer (score 30):

I found this approach much simpler:

```
import fs from 'fs';
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
  // File exists in path
} else {
  // File doesn't exist in path
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This one works for me

```js
 let file = 'ObjectCreatorBundles';
 fs.exists(file, (exist) => {
  if (exist) {
   console.log("I got your file")
  } else {
   console.log("the file doesn't exists");
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install file-exists  from npm (e.g. npm install file-exists --save)
2. fileExists('your file name', (err, exists) => console.log(exists))
3. Returns true if filepath exists and is a file